# Can't change input's contentEditable and value?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the input to contenteditable = false (preferably) or disabled when the select box's option = yes.

I have the if statement and then a switch statement for each case, but when I try to change the inputs contenteditable or the value, nothing changes.

Why wont the input change to contenteditable = false and the value be set to 0?

html:
`<input type="text" id="ca1"></input>`

```
<select id="ns1" onchange="test(this)">
        <option value="default" id="default" selected></option>
        <option value="yes">yes</option>
        <option value="no">no</option>
</select>
```

js:

```
function test(el)
{
  //if select box = yes, change contenteditable = false for cash and tip
  //and set values of cash and tip to 0
  if (el.value === "yes")
  {
    console.log("yes");

    //find what row has 'yes'
    var regex = /(\d+)/g;
    var string = el.id;
    var rowNumber = string.match(regex).toString();
    console.log(rowNumber);

    //make cash and tip contenteditable = false, change values to 0
    switch(rowNumber)
    {
      case 1:
        var ca1 = document.getElementById("ca1");
        ca1.value = 0;
        ca1.contentEditable = false; //.disabled = false doesn't work either
        break;
      case 2:
        //
        break;
      case 3:
        //
        break;
      case 4:
        //
        break;
      case 5:
        //
        break;
      default:
        //
    }
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("no");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are comparing a string to the number.

change this:

```
var rowNumber = string.match(regex).toString();
```

to

```
var rowNumber = parseInt(string.match(regex).toString());
```

Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odygnt7k/)

Comment: Thanks. The input with contentEditable = false can still be edited though. Disabling the input works, but I'd rather have it as contentEditable.

Comment: why do you want to have input contentEditable ? you can make it `readonly` also., if you dont like disable styling applied on it.

Answer (score 0):

1) Just use `Number()` in switch case

2) Add attribute `disabled` using `setAttribute()`

```js
function test(el)
{
  //if select box = yes, change contenteditable = false for cash and tip
  //and set values of cash and tip to 0
  if (el.value === "yes")
  {
    console.log("yes");

    //find what row has 'yes'
    var regex = /(\d+)/g;
    var string1 = el.id;
    alert(string1);
    var rowNumber = string1.match(regex).toString();
    console.log(rowNumber);

    //make cash and tip contenteditable = false, change values to 0
    switch(Number(rowNumber))
    {
      case 1:
        alert("1111");
        var ca1 = document.getElementById("ca1");
        ca1.value = 0;
        //ca1.contentEditable = false; //.disabled = false doesn't work either
       ca1.setAttribute("disabled", true);
        break;
     
      default:
        
    }
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("no");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ca1"></input>

<select id="ns1" onchange="test(this)">
        <option value="default" id="default" selected></option>
        <option value="yes">yes</option>
        <option value="no">no</option>
</select>
```